# How to have products on front-end only viewable to admin?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

We are trying to figure out if its possible to have the following logic on magento CE.

Admin adds products to Magento, but they are to be marked as admin viewable on the front-end only, which means customers will NOT be able to see those SPECIFIC products on the frontend.

Note: customers will still be able to view all the rest of the products on the site, except admin viewable products.

Answer (score 0):

Some products by customization can be made available for some certain customer groups.

So using logic related to this you can achieve your goal.